# How can I sum results in DAX by filtering out duplicate references and keeping latest entry

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI I have a table in my data model that looks like this, there are many Asset References but here are the rows corresponding to one of them:
Table
Lease Unit

| Asset Reference | Unit Reference | Leased Area | Status | Commencement Date | Expiration Date | Termination Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | AAA | 14654 | Active | 20-Jun-17 | 19-Jun-27 |  |
| 100 | BBB | 16387 | Active | 11-Aug-14 | 11-Feb-33 |  |
| 100 | CCC | 6597 | Active | 28-Jun-18 | 27-Jan-28 |  |
| 100 | DDD | 4747 | Active | 30-Apr-21 | 29-Apr-31 |  |
| 100 | EEE | 12366 | Active | 16-Aug-13 | 15-Aug-23 |  |
| 100 | CCC | 6597 | Holding | 28-Jan-08 | 27-Jan-18 |  |
| 100 | FFF | 2912 | Holding | 30-Jan-18 | 29-Jan-28 |  |
| 100 | GGG | 5177 | Holding | 06-Feb-18 | 05-Feb-28 |  |
| 100 | DDD | 4747 | Ended | 15-Jul-14 | 14-Jul-24 | 29-Apr-21 |
| 100 | DDD |  | Ended | 21-Nov-20 | 29-Jan-21 | 22-Nov-20 |

My matrix visual tries to sum Leased Area total for each Asset Reference - so one row for each Asset Reference

The above Asset Reference 100 is not working well with my DAX measure.

Basically, the following steps need to happen in the calculation. Note that [as of date]  is the date a user has chosen from a date picker in the report:

1. Filter keeping results where Commencement Date is <= [as of date] and Expiration Date >= [as of date]
   OR
   either Lease Status = "Holding" or Lease Status = "Month-to-Month"
2. Filter further keeping rows where Termination Date = blank or >= [as of date] if there is a date there
3. Filter further keeping the Leased Area value with the latest Commencement Date IF there is a duplicate Unit Reference. So in the case of Unit Reference CCC with the [as of date] being 31/12/2022 you'd want to keep the row with the Commencement Date of 28-Jan-18 and discard the earlier dated one.
4. SUM the above filtered results to give a total Leased Area for this particular Asset Reference

My DAX:

```
Total Leased Area (Current) = 
VAR asOfDate = [As Of Date]

VAR filtTblOne =
    FILTER (
        Lease_Unit,
        AND(Lease_Unit[Expiration Date] >= asOfDate, Lease_Unit[Commencement Date] <= asOfDate)
            || ( Lease_Unit[Lease Status] = "Holding"
            || Lease_Unit[Lease Status] = "Month-to-Month" )
    )
VAR filtTblTwo =
    FILTER (
        filtTblOne,
        Lease_Unit[Termination Date] = BLANK ()
            || Lease_Unit[Termination Date] >= asOfDate
    )

VAR filtTblThree = 
    FILTER (
        filtTblTwo,         
        Lease_Unit[Commencement Date] <= asOfDate
        && LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
            Lease_Unit[Unit Reference],max(Lease_Unit[Commencement Date])
        )
    )

RETURN


    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Lease_Unit_DST[Leased Area] ), filtTblThree )
```

In the above example, with an As Of Date selected by the user to be 31/12/2022, Asset 100 would have a total Leased Area of 62840 as there are duplicates of unit references CCC and DDD so the latest Commencement Date Leased Area values are taken. However, my DAX is incorrectly getting a Leased Area total of 69,437.

How can I solve this and is the DAX efficient enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try this measure:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE(
        Lease_Unit,
        Lease_Unit[Asset],
        Lease_Unit[Unit Reference],
        "Leased Area at Latest Date",
            CALCULATE(
                MIN( Lease_Unit[Leased Area] ),
                FILTER(
                    Lease_Unit,
                    Lease_Unit[Commencement Date] = MAX( Lease_Unit[Commencement Date] )
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX( T1, [Leased Area at Latest Date] )
```

Comment: Thanks @Jos. Does the solution account for the user selected [as of date]? It needs to be factored in somehow so that [Commencement Date] is < [as of date], otherwise I think you may end up favouring the latest Commencement Date but one that is in the future. It should capture only the latest one prior to the As Of Date.

Comment: @user3173215 No, I missed that part. How is your As Of Date slicer connected to the rest of your model?

Comment: it is basically a drop down date picker with between dates, but I blank out the from date from the user so they can only select end date. The end date is then assigned to the [as of date] measure and referenced in other measures I have. The date filter itself is connected to my Date Table

Comment: I have worked on some of the DAX and edited the OP to give a description of the bigger picture plus the rules i need in my DAX calculation - much of which is working already - it is just not quite adding up

Comment: Hi Jos, I appended your measure at the end of mine (see my amended OP), and I get a total of 59,928. However, it should be totalling 62,840.